# Android: Why can I update a TextView in a backgroud thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, textview

Android specifies that UI can´t be updated from a background thread, but if I run the next code, run without problems. Why I can update the TextView in the background thread?. The code updates a value (counter) in a textView called Contador every second.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView contador;
private int contadorTiempo=0;
private Button btnCnt10S;
private TextView cont10s;
private Button btnStart;
private Button btnStop;
private int cuenta=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnCnt10S = findViewById(R.id.idContBtn);
    contador = findViewById(R.id.contador);
    cont10s = findViewById(R.id.idCont10);
    btnStart = findViewById(R.id.idStartBtn);
    btnStop = findViewById(R.id.idStopBtn);


    btnCnt10S.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });

    btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           new Thread(new miRunable()).start(); 
        }
    });

    btnStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            contador.setText("0");
        }
    });
}


class miRunable implements Runnable{

    @Override
    public void run(){
        for(;;) {
            contadorTiempo++;
            contador.setText(Integer.valueOf(contadorTiempo).toString());

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

TLDR Don't do it, it's bad practice, or it's a bad code at all.

You can(with luck) update the View in the background thread. There's nothing that's monitoring it, that's why you got away with it. But it is not guaranteed that it will work everytime.

You'll eventually run into a race condition if android tries to update the view from the main thread.